Should the progress of Phd Students be transparent among group members?
I am using a weekly report system that every student in my group submit a weekly progress report.
I wonder should this be opened to all group members, or it should be just available between me and the individual PhD student?
What would be the pros and cons?
To clarify, this is not the format report that I will submit to university. Instead this is a way for me to keep track on the progress of different students' project. It includes things like what is done this week, what will be done next week, any difficulty, and if meeting is required, etc.
I am asking because I do see colleagues from no group meetings at all, to group meeting every week that every student report. It is from two extremes -- no communications to everything is open
I am in Asia, if region may make different answers.
P.S. I must clarify that I am not saying students reporting that they have pressure. Instead, my colleagues suggested me it should be open to my whole group to enhance communications. And in general, would that create pressure to students?

In the US it might be illegal to open it. What country are you proposing this in?

What actually goes into those reports? I am used to both daily and weekly meetings in which everyone updates everyone else. It’s kind of the point of working as a group, TBH.

@MisterMiyagi I am not sure from students' perspective I am trying to make them feel pressured by opening everyone's weekly progress report.

Now it sounds evil.

Well, I presumed it is between me and Individual PhD student, but some of my colleagues say it can be opened to enhance communications among group members, like the another comment above.

@Buffy: I guess there's a typo in Mahali Sindy's first comment. I believe what they intended to say is the following: "I am not sure whether, from the students' perspective, it might look like I am trying to make them feel pressured by opening everyone's weekly progress report."

@JochenGlueck, maybe the OP should clarify whether they intend this to increase pressure. Or if not, to explain, better, the reasoning.

‘And in general, would that create pressure to students?’ I imagine you already know the answer to that. You were in their shoes at one point.

I’m having a hard time finding anything but a list of "it depends" as potential answers. Should it be open? Depends. Is extra pressure bad? Depends. Are the extremes good? It depends. Can you aim for a middle ground? It depends. You probably could ask a more detailed question – e.g. what progress is worth sharing in a group, not just if progress is worth sharing – to make it objectively answerable.

To answer this, for me it would be interesting to know what the characteristic time-scales in your field are. Is what a student does in week k so much different than from week k+1? Specifically from the view of the other students (i.e. not just minor details about the implementation of the research)? I think for most fields this is a clear no.

I may have to amend this but if the students interpret this as increasing pressure, then it probably is, in fact, increasing pressure and that seems to be to exactly nobody's benefit. Artificially increasing pressure is a good way to get hated by one's students.
Students have a right, ethical if not always legal, to some privacy about their progress and standing. Some places it is a legal right.
If all you mean is handing out tasks and getting reports back later in front of the group, then it seems benign. Even allowing other students to comment/contribute to a report should be ok. But formal evaluation of those reports should be a private matter between you and the individual. And your headline question here is about their "progress", not just interim reporting.
Students also deal with a lot of pressure, just in learning, beyond contributing to a group/lab. That learning, from their standpoint, should be the primary goal, though yours may be otherwise.
A student under a lot of pressure who is struggling for any reason is more likely to fail (in some way) if pressure is increased, even if without specific intention. Their failure can contribute to the group's failure if their contributions are poorly done or not done at all.
I suggest, pretty strongly, that you avoid such things. And, not just for fairness to the students, but to the efficiency and success of the group.
Lots of questions here from students call advisors to account for belittling them in public.
Avoid a lose-lose possible outcome.

My supervisor used to do group meetings where we would all give a brief update on what we'd been working on. This was once a month rather than once a week though. I found it helpful to hear about what his other PhD students had been up to. I think the important part is that our group in general had a positive atmosphere and it was okay that sometimes the update was "I haven't made much progress this month." I think it was good for us all to hear that other people also had periods where they didn't make much progress! It was also good practice communicating about our research in front of a small group, and we took it in turns to give more in depth presentations about our work.
I think a more informal update during a meeting will create less pressure than having to submit a written report. I also can't imagine really being interested in reading written progress reports from other PhD students.
